# insert home icon on wordpress menu, impossible according to theme creator => what do you think?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I ve asked support on yithemes for the theme BAZAR (i bought it on themeforest) but i couldnt manage to insert a house icon instead of "home" in the menu.

Support told me its impossible, nothing is impossible dont you think?

you can check the demo theme on this link

http://demo.yithemes.com/bazar/shop/ankle-shoes/

Hoep someone will help!

Ive tried css on the menu editor and in css itself but nothing seems to work.

Cheers

Comment: Are you willing to open up the php files and replace the "HOME" text with an image tag? Or are you trying to do this from within the Wordpress dashboard?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.wpexplorer.com/adding-images-wordpress-menu/
Here is a tutorial on just that.

You will need some CSS and if you don't want to see the text you could try

```
color:transparent;
```

or

```
color:rgba(0,0,0,0);
```

You can add the css in your themes "custom" CSS area or if that isn't available go to Appearance>Editor and edit style.css . I don't recommend the latter as theme changes/updates will remove any of your custom code.

And in wordpress, many things are "impossible" just not that one.